# How to reenable disabled menu items in qt mac application

Tags: c++, macos, qt

The menu of my qt application gets disabled and can only be reenabled with a hack.

I have a qt application (QApplication with QMainWindow) with different modes, each mode has it's own menu. To change the menu when switching between the modes, I have subclassed QMenuBar and store the set of QMenu pointers as members. When switching between modes, I call `QMenuBar::clear()`, followed by iterating through all the stored menus and calling `QMenuBar::addMenu(QMenu*)`.

After switching the application mode, some of my menu items are disabled in the GUI and I cannot interact with them. However, `isEnabled()` returns true for all `QMenu*` or `QAction*` items.

Once I open another modal window and close it again, the menu items are available. To programmatically enable them, I found this ugly hack:

```
ActivateMenu(QMenu* aMenu)
{
   QList<QAction*> vActions = aMenu->actions();
   for (bpSize vI = 0; vI < vActions.size(); ++vI) {
     QAction* vAction = vActions[vI];
     std::string vOldTitle = vAction->text().toStdString();
     std::string vNewTitle = "X" + vOldTitle;
     vAction->setText(vNewTitle.c_str());
     vAction->setText(vOldTitle.c_str());
   }
 }
```

The source of `QAction::setText(...)` is

```
void QAction::setText(const QString &text)
{
  Q_D(QAction);
  if (d->text == text)
    return;

  d->text = text;
  d->sendDataChanged();
}
```

and I guess it is the call `d->sendDataChanged()` which is restoring the correct state of my action items.

Unfortunately I cannot reproduce the issue in a toy application to post here.

This works fine on windows, I only have issues on mac. I'm using Qt 4.8.7 64bit.

- Is this a known problem/QT bug (I first thought it was [this QT Bug](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-26399), but the bug sample program does work fine with my installed QT version)?
- Is it wrong to store the QMenu* items, should I rather completely rebuild them? The [QAction documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qaction.html) states that:

> An action will be disabled when all widgets to which it is added (with QWidget::addAction()) are disabled or not visible. When an action is disabled, it is not possible to trigger it through its shortcut.

This should be the case how I use them, but QMenu/QAction `isEnabled()` return true, and `setEnabled(true)` does not help...

- Is there a better way to correct the enabled state than with my hack?